# Purposeful uneven spacing between nav elements

Tags: html, css

I have a nav in a header with 4 basic elements in a list I want spaced evenly.  I have no issue getting that to work.

```
<nav>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="resume.html" >Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html" class="selected" >Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
```

CSS:

```
nav{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px 0;
  margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

nav ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 30px;
  padding: 2px 20px 0 0;


}
nav li{
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

nav a{
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2px 10px 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:active{
    color: #00A2E0;
}

nav a{
    color: #fff;
}
nav a.selected, nav a:hover{
    color: #23c3ff;
}
```

However, I want a link to another item in the list, let's call it feed, that I want inline with the rest of the nav, but float to the right of the page.  I wish I could simply add a nav around a new list item:

```
<div class="feed"><li><a href="feed.html">feed</a></li></div>
```

and style it like:

```
.feed{
   float: right;
}
```

but that forces the other 4 items in the list to move to the left since text-align: center would now be centered based on the center point from the p of portfolio to the d in feed.  Since I want the feed to wrap in the nav, I can't just ignore the feed item (I also want it in a div since I want slightly different styling to it than the rest of the nav items).

Anyway, is there a way to keep my nav intact and make adjustments to allow for the original 4 items (portfolio, about, resume and contact) to hold center in the header and have feed spaced further to the right but still keep it wrapped in the same nav?

Many thanks!

Comment: maybe so http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/owjcpp2j/?

Answer (score 1):

Is **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/zcn9qdps/)** what you meant?

I used absolute positioning on the `#feed` `li` and added position relative to the `ul` so that the newly position `#feed` element would not interfere with the centering.

**UPDATED HTML**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html" class="selected">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li id="feed">
            <a href="feed.html">feed</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**UPDATED CSS**

```
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 30px;
    padding: 2px 20px 0 0;
    position: relative;
}
#feed {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Yea, that's definitely the best I have so far, thank you.  The only issue with the positioning is window resizing.  Narrowing the width will bring the feed id inwards and eventually overlap the rest of the lap once the size gets too narrow.

Comment: Maybe you could use media queries for specific window/screen sizes so that the layout could adapt according to the window dimensions.